# Telerik MVC Q1 2011 Grid with Ajax Edit breaks when Serializing Dictionary Object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, telerik-grid, javascriptserializer

Telerik MVC Q1 2011 has the following listed as the very first breaking change:

---

**Changes from Q3 2010 Service Pack 1 (Assembly version 2010.3.1318)**

**Breaking Changes**

**The whole data item is sent to the server during Ajax editing**
The grid now sends the whole data item object to the server during ajax editing. Before that only editable fields were submitted.

---

Not sure whether that is the cause of my problem or not, but my grid with Ajax editing enabled is indeed broken now when it was working fine before. Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do to fix it.

I am going to assume that if you are offering help with Telerik-related issues, you also have access to [my post on the Telerik forum](http://bit.ly/eGlqVf). There, I have two projects attached as an example of the problem. They are identical except one is using Telerik MVC Q3 2010 and works, and the other is using Telerik MVC Q1 2011 and does not work.

**Exception Details:** System.ArgumentException: Type 'blah' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Please check out the examples, and let me know how to get back in business with the latest version.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it was just a bug.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/q1-2011-breaks-ajax-edit-when-serializing-dictionary-object.aspx